# how to set a timeout to infinity in javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have a timeout event that I want to set to infinity. Right now I just set it to `9999999` meaning that after that many milliseconds the event will trigger. But it is not so elegant, what's a better way to make it infinite?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you don't want the event to ever fire, don't schedule it in the first place.

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts only 32 bit integers so you cannot have a threshold more than `2^31 -1` i.e. `2,147,483,647`

Comment: @Barmar Say you have a function which returns a promise but you need timeout functionality as well, then you may do like `timeoutFetch(url, timeout = 2147483647){ return new Promise((v,x) => (setTimeout(_ => x("fetch timed out"), timeout), v(fetch(url))));};`. So `2147483647` is the default `timeout` argument value which takes effect if it is not provided like `timeoutFetch(url,200)` but `timeoutFetch(url)`.

Comment: @Redu you could just do `if (timeout) setTimeout(...)`, as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to trigger event after infinity time. Doing that will make events stays in stack forever and they could pile up.

Correct approach:

```
let booleanFlag = false;

// do somethinghing that can change "booleanFlag" value

function triggerThisOnSomeEvent() {
    if (booleanFlag) {
        // Handle event
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are new to JS and don't know what `let` does - it's basically same as `var`

Comment: If `booleanFlag` is a function parameter, the global variable is not needed.